# checkbox not checking via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to check the checkbox using Jquery but to no avail. Following is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var url_brand_alias = $("#hidden_brand_alias").val(); //gives a,b
   var url_brand_arr = url_brand_alias.split(',');
   $.each(url_brand_arr, function(key, value) {
       $('input.Brand[rel="'+value+'"]').attr('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Checkbox html:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="filters-type">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="a" value="1" class="Brand">a</label>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="filters-type"><input type="checkbox" rel="b" value="2" class="Brand">b</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using both attr and prop but to no avail. I have no any error in console also. Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the value of `url_cat_arr`. Is it a typo? Is it meant to be `url_brand_arr` by any chance?

Comment: Can you include a fiddle or JSBin to your code?

Comment: sorry it's just typo mistake.

Comment: From where did you copy your jQuery code? Where are you initializing those ids?

Comment: I have url with GET parameter. These values are stored as hidden values.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6os2hvka/ if value is REALLY 'a,b' -> this will work, try to trim $("#hidden_brand_alias").val(); Btw, how many hidden inputs are on page?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a simple line `url_brand_alias = "a,b";` gives the desired result, suggesting `$("#hidden_brand_alias").val(); //gives a,b` does not in fact return `"a,b"` as expected. Consider investigating that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var url_brand_alias = $("#hidden_brand_alias").val(); //gives a,b
   url_brand_alias = "a,b";
   var url_brand_arr = url_brand_alias.split(',');
   $.each(url_brand_arr, function(key, value) {
       $('input.Brand[rel="'+value+'"]').attr('checked', true);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="filters-type">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="a" value="1" class="Brand">a
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="filters-type">
            <input type="checkbox" rel="b" value="2" class="Brand">b
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for all the response and the time. I did a mistake of unchecking the checkbox on document ready function. The solution is found after I tried checking the checkbox using setTimeout() function. Using setTimeout() function checked all the required checkbox. So, I searched for whether the checkbox is unchecked at some point and it was true.

Answer (score 0):

To change checkbox state with help of jQuery you should use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$( elem ).prop( "checked", true )
```

To get the value, use `prop()` too:

```
$( elem ).prop( "checked" )
```

Here's jQuery `prop` docs: http://api.jquery.com/prop/